# 'Could not load type' error calling membership method from within asp.net mvc migrations seed method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, membership-provider

I'm using the Seed method within configuration.cs that's created when you turn on Code First Migrations in an ASP.Net MVC project.

All my usual `context.ENTITYHERE.AddOrUpdate` calls are working great. The problem comes when I attempt to setup some users with [this membership provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com):

`Could not load type 'CodeFirstMembershipSharp.CodeFirstMembershipProvider' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

If I disable the 'Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password, Email, null, null, IsApproved, null, out CreateStatus);' line in WebSecurity.cs, it appears to be ok..!

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you ever get to the bottom of this? I've ran into the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I've now realised this isn't that helpful as it uses an entirely different membership provider (although similar). I'm still not sure how best to resolve this but left my answer up as I hope it might help.**

I know this is massively old now but I found a solution installing the latest providers. This link has the required information:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

Interestingly the web.config changes that were automatically made seem to include more information than the old.

My old provider lines were:

```html
<membership defaultProvider="CodeFirstMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" type="CodeFirstMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="[YOURCONNECTIONNAME]" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CodeFirstRoleProvider">
        <providers>
          <clear />
          <add name="CodeFirstRoleProvider" type="CodeFirstRoleProvider" connectionStringName="[YOURCONNECTIONNAME]" />
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
```

The new provider code looks like this:

```html
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="[YOURCONNECTIONNAME]" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </profile>
      <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
           <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="[YOURCONNECTIONNAME]" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
        <providers>
           <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="[YOURCONNECTIONNAME]" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
```